# how to stop auto log out google account from browsers on linux (ubuntu, fedora)

Tags: 22.04, kubuntu, firefox, google-chrome, google

just installed ubuntu and logged in to google, but when i close the browser it logout from account,
clear browser data when close option is disabled by default,
same issue with fedora,

Are there any permissions to give to browser to store the logged in accounts? Or is it dual boot issue?
only getting logout from google account like chrome says sync paused, and logged out of google account
help me, I am new to linux

Comment: Unable to reproduce in the stock Ubuntu Desktop 23.10 Firefox browser. Restarting the browser, I don't need to re-login to AskUbuntu. Please provide the detailed steps to reproduce.

Comment: @user535733 i dont know how to reproduce this issue but its there by default, and i dual booted Ubuntu with windows 10,

Comment: There is no such feature in Ubuntu. firefox is a snap by default so is not even allowed to execute anything in the OS.. Are you sure you do not use incognito?

Comment: @Rinzwind i am not using incognito, i am using normal window and its happening with all the browsers i installed not only on ubuntu also facing this same issue with fedora

Comment: @user535733 now i logged in to askUbuntu and chatGpt i am not getting logged out, 
only google account getting logged out

Comment: now it starte working, can anyone explain why this weird thing is happening? :/}